# In Python, iteration doesn't work as I intended

Tags: python

i of iteration "for" do not grow. Although the i do not grow, the plain is infinitely adhered to the '@'

program : This is find width and height as close to the square as possible. So If length of string is prime number, string += "@" and re-calculate.

```
def build_size(plain: str, length: int, length_name: int):

    def size_control(plain, length):  return plain + "@", length + 1

    print(f"length : {length} | length_name {length_name} \n plain : {plain}") #debug
    input("continue? : ") #debug

    while True:

        try:

            print(f"plain : {plain}") #debug

            aliquot = list()

            for i in range(int(length // 2) + 1):

                print(f"i : {i}") #debug

                if length % i == 0:

                    aliquot.append(i)

            if len(aliquot) < 2 or aliquot[-1] <= length_name: raise NotImplementedError


            break

        except: plain, length = size_control(plain, length)

    return plain, aliquot[-1] , length // aliquot[-1]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    name  = input("name : ")

    plain = input("plain : ")

    build_size(plain, len(plain), len(name))
```

How can I do? Please help me.

Comment: How do you call `build_size`? With what parameters? Please add to your question.

Comment: Exceptions for *flow control*?! Yeegh. And dangerous; a bare `except:` will often hide exceptions other than the sole one you designed your logic expecting it to catch.

Comment: You have an infinite loop with `while True` and most of your function wrapped in a try/except with a bare except statement where you're burying the exception. You are probably just getting some exception over and over again. Remove the try/except for now and see what the exception is.

Comment: I can't see what the exception would be without knowing your inputs. Maybe it's just the one you're raising yourself (there is probably a better way to do this). In any case right now it's impossible to tell, and anyhow you're not reaching the condition to break out of your loop. Please have a look at [How to debug small programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason `i` does not grow is that your `while` loop always raises an error on the first pass of the `for` loop. So the `for` loop ends, the `while` loop advances, and `i` gets set back to 0.

Speaking of 0, I think that's your problem. When you call [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) with only one argument, the starting point defaults to 0, not 1. Anything modulo 0 is undefined, so `length % i` always throws a ZeroDivisionError, which your bare `except:` clause always catches.

*Edit:* To fix this bug, I suggest two things. First, start your range at 1 instead of zero, replacing that line with something like:

```
for i in range(1, int(length // 2) + 1):
```

Second, try to avoid bare `except:` clauses. If you had used `except NotImplementedError:` instead, then it wouldn't have caught the ZeroDivisionError, and you would have seen the normal error message and been able to figure out the problem much more easily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a rudimentary mistake of dividing it by zero and finding the rest. I would like to express my deep gratitude to your generosity for understanding the function and solving the problem, even though only the function existed.